# Has and Belongs to many associations doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm getting crazy with this HABTM association.

I have 2 classes

```
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
  establish_connection Rails.application.config.dday_companies_database_configuration
  scope :default_order, -> { order :name }
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contents, join_table: :brands_contents, foreign_key: :content_id
end

class Content < ApplicationRecord
 has_and_belongs_to_many :brands, class_name: 'Brand', join_table: :brands_contents, association_foreign_key: :brand_id
end
```

The brand class table is on another database.

I have my migration

```
    class CreateContentBrandJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :brands, :contents do |t|
      t.index [:brand_id, :content_id]
    end
  end
end
```

And so I have my join table

```
--
-- Name: brands_contents; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE TABLE brands_contents (
    brand_id integer NOT NULL,
    content_id bigint NOT NULL
);
```

By the way when I try my association I have this error

> [6] pry(main)> c.brands.first ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "content_brands" does not exist
>   LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid =
>   '"content_brands"'::regcla...
>                                             ^ :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
>                        pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
>                        c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
>                   FROM pg_attribute a
>                   LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
>                   LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
>                   LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
>                  WHERE a.attrelid = '"content_brands"'::regclass
>                    AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
>                  ORDER BY a.attnum

Why is looking for `content_brands` ??

Comment: why are you using in one case `foreign_key` and in the other `:association_foreign_key`?